# Binomial GLMM not converging / Random effects variance and stdev = 1 resulting in AIC = Inf

Tags: binomial-distribution, random-effects-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I am using a binomial GLMM to assess differential habitat selection between two species with model selection using AIC.

When I use many variables (8), the models converge but are not significant. However, when I reduce the number of variables the models either do not converge or have an AIC of 'Inf'.

AIC: Inf occurs when both the Variance and StdDev of the (only) Random Effect both equal 1 (or close to 1). Sample results:

```
> M3ghq <- glmer(pt.type ~ 
+               em.dens + float.dens + l.hard.dep + l.near.edge + l.veg.ht
+               + (1 | frog), 
+               data = Frogs.st, family = binomial, nAGQ = 3)

> M3ghq       
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
Formula: pt.type ~ em.dens + float.dens + l.hard.dep + l.near.edge + l.veg.ht +  
(1 | frog) 
   Data: Frogs.st 

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance 
     Inf      Inf     -Inf      Inf 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 frog   (Intercept) 1.004    1.002   
Number of obs: 481, groups: frog, 23

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -5.6090     1.2866  -4.359 1.30e-05 ***
em.dens       0.4853     0.8733   0.556  0.57841    
float.dens  -10.5272     2.0428  -5.153 2.56e-07 ***
l.hard.dep   -3.5192     1.3036  -2.700  0.00694 ** 
l.near.edge   1.4862     0.8095   1.836  0.06636 .  
l.veg.ht      7.6150     1.8149   4.196 2.72e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) em.dns flt.dn l.hrd. l.nr.d
em.dens      0.168                            
float.dens   0.781  0.038                     
l.hard.dep   0.639  0.154  0.776              
l.near.edge -0.280  0.192 -0.470 -0.468       
l.veg.ht    -0.820 -0.290 -0.751 -0.713  0.476

> drop1(M3ghq)
Single term deletions

Model:
pt.type ~ em.dens + float.dens + l.hard.dep + l.near.edge + l.veg.ht + 
    (1 | frog)
            Df AIC
<none>         Inf
em.dens      1 Inf
float.dens   1 Inf
l.hard.dep   1  50
l.near.edge  1 Inf
l.veg.ht     1 Inf
```

Why does this happen? I'm suspicious that it might be because all the responses for each cluster (random effect) are the same. In my data, there is no variability in the response ('pt.type' = species) of each cluster ('frog' = individual). I am seeking the differential response of each species to the explanatory variables, while accounting for autocorrelation within individual responses.

Is there an assumption to GLMMs that I've missed where each group must have some probability of having a response of either 1 or 0?

Is there a mathematical reason why it shouln't work?

If this were a problem, why would it converge at greater complexity?

Answer (score 2):

(Revisiting this problem while trying to close out old `lme4` issues)

On reflection, I just don't think it makes sense to build a binomial (Bernoulli) GLMM where the responses don't vary at all within levels of the grouping variable. If we do something like this (i.e. each frog has either all-zero or all-one responses), then we can make the model fit perfectly by allowing the random effects for each frog to go to -infinity (for 0 responses) or +infinity (for 1 responses).  When I fit this model using the latest development version of `lme4`, I get a very large standard deviation for the `frog` random effect and non-significant values for all of the predictors, which is consistent with my diagnosis. I do get some wonky results -- in particular, I get an AIC for the full model that is *more* than 2 units worse than for the one-parameter-reduced model, which should be impossible.  I conclude that the model specification is, more or less, pathological ... (I agree that `glmer` **should** tell you that something is wrong, but I think it has an excuse when trying to fit a model that turns out not to be sensible.)

My recommendation would be to collapse all of the predictors for each individual frog by averaging them (you could use other summary statistics [median, maximum, minimum, etc.], or more than one, if you thought it was more appropriate) and then do a regular GLM fit on the reduced data.  This is analogous, although I think not quite identical, to Murtaugh (2007)'s suggestion of reducing nested ANOVA analyses to their aggregated equivalents (in a nested design, the treatment variables are identical for all individuals within a group; in this case, the response variables are identical ...)  This will mean you only have 23 frogs left, but I actually think that's a more realistic representation of the amount of data you have.  Similarly to the way that things work when you aggregate data from a nested design, the aggregation should give you a better estimate of the characteristic habitat of an individual ...

Further discussion of the technical details of `lme4` might continue at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/21

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the model runs just fine on a PC, and I'm working on a Mac. I'm using the development version of lme4, and this appears to be a bug associated with the operating environment.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you please send me the data (my e-mail is easily googlable ...)?  I would very much like to see if I can see what the problem is.